# How to chain api calls with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angualrJS and web development in general. I have a controller named `FavoritesCtrl` that makes an api call and returns an object.

My controller looks like this:

```
controllers.controller('FavoritesCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
  $http.jsonp('https://api...=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (scooby){
    $scope.list=scooby.data;
  });
});
```

I access the returned data in my html with this:

```
<div ng-controller="FavoritesCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="favorite in list.favorites">
<div>product_id: {{ favorite.product_id }} </div>
```

I need to send that `{{ favorite.product.id  }}` back as a parameter in another api call so I can generate an affiliate link, but I don't know the most angular way to do it.

Should I attempt to send the second call in the `FavoritesCtrl` or would it make sense to put it in a new controller?

I can get the proper affiliate link back with something like this:

```
controllers.controller('FavoritesCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
  $http.jsonp('https://api...=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (scooby){
    $scope.list=scooby.data;

    var length = scooby.data.favorites.length;
    var i;

    for (i=0;i<length;i+=1){
      var getProductId = scooby.data.favorites[i].product_id;
      $http.jsonp('https://api...+getProductId+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (fred){
      console.log(fred.data.link);
    });
  });
});
```

But I can't figure out a good way to display this on my page with the associated item. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  I think in your for loop in the controller, just put $scope.list.favorites[i].affiliateLink = [whatever the returned value of the specific affiliate link should be];

Then in the HTML, it would just interpolate as {{favorite.affiliateLink}}

Comment: I think either my answer or the answer describing the ng-click approach will work.  It is just a question of when you want to compute the value of the affiliate link - as the page is being rendered, or when the user clicks the link.  I personally err on the side of keeping as many functions in the controller as possible, but this is really just an opinion, and could be done either way.

Comment: I took a stab at this and ran into trouble. I updated the loop in the controller with this:`$scope.list.favorites[i].get_link = fred.data.link;` It errors with this message: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'get_link' of undefined" I'm either not getting the scope correct or is it possible that I can't add a property to an object retrieved by the api call?

Comment: I refactored my code a bit and got it working. First before the loop, I added a new property to $scope: `$scope.links = [];` and then I added this to the loop: `$scope.links.push(fred.data.link);`.  Ultimately I do think the suggestion from @ncabral to use promises is probably the more Angular way to do this, but it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use ng-click and this will call another method in your controller:

```
<li><a ng-click="doSomething(favorite.product_id)" href="">{{favorite.product_id}}</a></li>
```

in your controller :

```
$scope.doSomething = function (prodId) {
  // Do whatever you want here
};
```

Comment: In this case, I want the affiliate link generated immediately. I'll explore this technique for other features though.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a more elegant way using a tool that you already have - promises. Promises are there to help you chain events like this.

A simple example would be:

```
get('story.json').then(function(response) {
  return JSON.parse(response);
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log("Yey JSON!", response);
});
```

A very good introduction to promises can be found here [1].

[1] http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/